# Lilypond: superscript in lyrics

Tags: superscripts, lilypond

I would like to know how I can add a superscript to lyrics in Lilypond. Example:

[image: example of whhat I want to get.]

I know how to do markups, but that's not what I am looking for. It's about the 1 and the 2 in the lyrics.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `\markup` inside `\lyricsmode`, which will allow you to use any Lilypond markup, including subscripts and superscripts.

**Example**

[image: A Lilypond staff with lyrics. The lyrics are the words "one two three four five six seven eight," but the word "four" is in superscript. There is a superscript digit 5 after the word "five," and a subscript digit 7 after the word "seven."]

```tex
<<
  \new Voice = "myVoice" \relative c' {
    c4 d e f g a b c 
  }
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "myVoice" {
    \lyricmode {
      One
      Two
      Three
      \markup{\super Four}
      \markup{\concat{Five\super 5}}
      Six
      \markup{\concat{Seven\sub 7}}
      Eight
    }
  }
>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!